# SS5 <maxcons> limitation issue with <group>

Tags: linux, sql-server, authentication, socks

Have an SS5 Socks proxy server running with SS5_RADIUS_AUTH

I want to set a max connections users but have run in to a problem.

SS5 want's me to define user group for it.

```
<group>
define a filename in the configuration directory containing one or more usernames for
which limit bandwidth or number of connections.
note: if you add/remove a user from group file, ss5 requires reload.
```

Can't this be done without this file ? Just limitit it towards all users with * or something ? Users will come and go so restarting it every time is not optimal.

Did try this but it did not limit the maxcons but was not successful

```
 bandwidth - 100 - -
```

Would need to advice here.

Comment: Way to solve this is using mysql profiling. But don't get it to work 

mysql_profile_ip xxxx
mysql_profile_db    xxxxx
mysql_profile_user  xxxxx
mysql_profile_pass  xxxxx
mysql_profile_sqlstring SELECT username FROM radcheck


Wont start with this in config :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Users must be put in a file

Create a file in the same directory that contain ss5.conf and call it users and in it add one username on ever row

```
userA
userB
userC
```

Then you need to add this line in your ss5.conf

```
bandwidth   users           60           -           -
```

To not need to stop and start your ss5 your don't want to use

```
service ss5 restart
```

What you wan't to use is

```
service ss5 reload
```

There is not really any other good solution right now. If it is i would like to know ab